# Python Keras Model -- ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 input(s), but it received 16 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have seen that many others on stackoverflow have posted about this same problem, but I haven't been able to figure out how to apply those solutions to my example.

I have been working on creating a model to predict an outcome of either 0 or 1 based on a dataset which contains 16 features - Everything has seemed to work fine (accuracy evaluation, epoch completion, etc.).

As mentioned, my training features include 16 different variables, but when I pass in a list that contains 16 unique values separate from the training dataset in order to try and make an individual prediction (of either 0 or 1), I get this error:

```
ValueError: Layer sequential_11 expects 1 input(s), but it received 16 input tensors.
```

Here is my code -

```
y = datas.Result
X = datas.drop(columns = ['Date', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'home_pitcher', 'away_pitcher', 'Result'])

X = X.values.astype('float32')
y = y.values.astype('float32')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.2)
X_train, X_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

model=keras.Sequential([
           keras.layers.Dense(32, input_shape = (16,)),
           keras.layers.Dense(20,activation=tf.nn.relu),                           
           keras.layers.Dense(2,activation='softmax')
        ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=20, validation_data=(X_validation, y_validation))

#all variables within features list are single values, ex: .351, 11, .991, etc.
features = [t1_pqm,t2_pqm,t1_elo,t2_elo,t1_era,t2_era,t1_bb9,t2_bb9,t1_fip,t2_fip,t1_ba,t2_ba,t1_ops,t2_ops,t1_so,t2_so]
prediction = model.predict(features)
```

Comment: Can you try ```input_shape = (1, 16)```?

Comment: @KaziSohan just tried, unfortunately gave the same error

Comment: Please tell shape of `X_train,y_train,X_validation, y_validation`

Comment: @Kaveh X_train.shape: (8,16)   y_train.shape: (8,)   X_validation.shape: (3,16)  y_validation.shape: (3,)

Answer (score 0):

The model expects an input of shape `(None,16)` but features has the shape `(16,)` (1D list). The easiest solution is to make it an numpy array with the right shape `(1, 16)`:

```
features = np.array([[t1_pqm,t2_pqm,t1_elo,t2_elo,t1_era,t2_era,t1_bb9,t2_bb9,t1_fip,t2_fip,t1_ba,t2_ba,t1_ops,t2_ops,t1_so,t2_so]])
```

Comment: just plugged that in and got this back:   ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_15 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 16 but received input with shape (None, 16, 1)

Comment: I just used np.reshape and I think its working properly now